# é is showing as a question mark?

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding, special-characters

The é is shown as a diamond with a question mark in the middle, and on the web page it throws an invalid charachter UTF-8 byte 1 of 1 byte string.

Is there a UTF safe way to display the é sign? Here is an example of what I am doing at the moment.

[image]

This is the picture of the error.

Comment: Just encode you html in UTF8 and set proper meta/headers.

Comment: i have proper meta tags And UTF8

Comment: Then check encoding applied by your browser, sometimes it might conflict, if possible set it to "autodetect"

Comment: Depends on the browser you use, just do a google search.

Answer (score 2):

é is E9 in utf-8, or in decimal the 233th character

you can hardcode the accent into html with this format

```
&#233;
```

or

```
&#xE9;
```

for example

```
1 avenue des Champs Ely&#xE9;es
```